# EasyPHP local site doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, webserver, easyphp

### I've installed EasyPHP, copy into "www" folder my site, but when i try to open it there is server error:

Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

### If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Log from Apache log file:

.htaccess: Invalid command 'SecFilterEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Who can help me!? How resolve that problem?
Thanks

Comment: Post your htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try remove .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error:
"Invalid command 'SecFilterEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included"

It is because you have not included the ":LoadModule security_module modules/mod_security.so" in the httpd.conf.

Another posible reason is that you are using mod_security2 and the SecFilterEngine is obsolete and you should migrate it to SecRuleEngine as is explained in the migration document.

http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/ModSecurity-Migration-Matrix.pdf